# Build a CodeEffect Rule

Tags: rule, codeeffects

Is there a way to build a ruleset in codeeffects from a string? The default way over the ASP/MVC RuleEditor is currently not an option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use RuleXML if you want to build your rules dynamically outside of our editor. It's a common way of creating rules in Code Effects. String representation is too generic to be useful in rule generation. Details on RuleXML can be found [here](http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rules-Storage).

Also, please take a look at SourceXML; it allows you to generate your source objects dynamically, too. This is a MUCH more flexible approach for source handling that plain .NET objects. Details can be found [here](http://codeeffects.com/Doc/Business-Rule-Source-Object-Xml).